# computing differences between groups: alternative to spread for multiple computations

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I commonly need to compute differences between groups, nested by some interval and/or additional grouping. For computing a single variable, this is easy to accomplish with `spread` and `mutate`. Here's a reproducible example with the dataset`ChickWeight`; don't get distracted by the calculation itself (this is just a toy example), my question is about how to handle a dataset structured like the dataframe `ChickSum` created below.

```r
# reproducible dataset
data(ChickWeight)
ChickSum = ChickWeight %>% 
  filter(Time == max(Time) | Time == min(Time)) %>%
  group_by(Diet, Time) %>% 
  summarize(mean.weight = mean(weight)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Here is how I might go about calculating the change in average chick weight between the first and last time, stratified by diet:

```r
# Compute change in mean weight between first and last time
ChickSum %>%
  spread(Time, mean.weight) %>%
  mutate(weight.change = `21` - `0`)
```

However, this doesn't work so well with multiple variables:

```r
ChickSum2 = ChickWeight %>% 
  filter(Time == max(Time) | Time == min(Time)) %>%
  group_by(Diet, Time) %>% 
  # now also compute variable "count"
  summarize(count = n(), mean.weight = mean(weight)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

I can't spread by `Time` and both `count` and `mean.weight`; my current solution is to do two `spread`-`mutate` operations---once for `count` and again for `mean.weight`---and then `join` the results.

```r
ChickCountChange = ChickSum2 %>%
  select(-mean.weight) %>%
  spread(Time, count) %>%
  mutate(count.change = `21` - `0`)
ChickWeightChange = ChickSum2 %>%
  select(-count) %>%
  spread(Time, mean.weight) %>%
  mutate(weight.change = `21` - `0`)

full_join(
  select(ChickWeightChange, Diet, weight.change), 
  select(ChickCountChange, Diet, count.change), 
  by = "Diet")
```

**Is there another approach to these types of computation?** I've been trying to conceive of a strategy that combines `group_by` and `purrr::pmap` in order to avoid `spread` but still maintain the advantages of the above approach (such as `spread`'s `fill` argument for choosing how to handle missing group combinations), but I haven't figured it out. I'm open to suggestions or alternative data structures/ways of thinking about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You might try re-grouping, then using `lag()` to calculate the differences. Works for your toy example, but it may be better to see some of your real dataset:

```
ChickWeight %>% 
  filter(Time == max(Time) | Time == min(Time)) %>%
  group_by(Diet, Time) %>% 
  # now also compute variable "count"
  summarize(count = n(), mean.weight = mean(weight)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(Diet) %>% 
  mutate(count.change = count - lag(count), 
         weight.change = mean.weight - lag(mean.weight)) %>% 
  filter(Time == max(Time))
```

Result:

```
  Diet   Time count mean.weight count.change weight.change
  <fct> <dbl> <int>       <dbl>        <int>         <dbl>
1 1        21    16        178.           -4          136.
2 2        21    10        215.            0          174 
3 3        21    10        270.            0          230.
4 4        21     9        239.           -1          198.
```

Comment: This is a good approach, and one I have used before---but it's not as clear cut if your inner group (in this example, `Time`) needs some custom ordering, and/or if the calculation is more complex that a simple difference. I suppose you could enforce an order by using `factor` levels for the inner group, and a complex calculation could use be achieved with multiple `lag` statements with different `n` values to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

So I came up with a potential/partial solution in the process of writing up a reproducible example. Essentially, we use `gather` to group by the variables themselves:

```r
ChickSum2 %>% 
  gather(variable, value, count, mean.weight) %>% 
  spread(Time, value) %>% mutate(Change = `21` - `0`) %>% 
  select(Diet, variable, Change) %>% 
  spread(variable, Change)
```

This works only if the following two conditions are true:

1. All variables are the same type (e.g. both `mean.weight` and `count` are numeric).
2. the difference calculation is the same for all variables (e.g. I want to compute `last - first` for all variables).

I guess the second condition could be relaxed by using e.g. `case_when`.